# How to get a dependency of another dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a package ([`babel-preset-es2015-webpack`](https://github.com/gajus/babel-preset-es2015-webpack)) with dependency `babel-preset-es2015`. `babel-preset-es2015` have dependency `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`.

How do I require `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` in a way to make sure that it is the same package that my `babel-present-es2015` dependency is using?

Simply doing:

```
require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs');
```

Will work in NPM3 setup (assuming there are no other dependencies that require a different version of `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`), but will not work in NPM2.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use `shrinkwrap` as noted by @Nocturno, you can also simply require the specific path to the dependency:

```
require('<path-to-node_modules>/babel-preset-es2015-webpack/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs');
```

Never used the plugins myself, but something like the above should work.

Another option is to lock down `babel-preset-es2015-webpack` to a specific version, then determine what version of `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` is listed in it's package.json and add it to your package.json. Then you can use the `require('babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs');` method in NPM2 and NPM3.

Comment: See my edited response above, I can't really think of another way to do it unfortunately.

Comment: Tip: Use `require.resolve` to get path of `<target module>`. Then write an iterator that attmpts to resolve `<target module>/node_modules/<target dependency>`, then (if `<target dependency>` is not resolved) proceeds to `<target module>/../node_modules/<target dependency>`, `<target module>/../../node_modules/<target dependency>`. This will work in npm v2 and npm v3. Giving you the answer. Just need to put it in code. : )

Comment: Awesome! Good to know